# Set geom_tile height and width in cm/in

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make a `geom_tile` of datasets with different number of variables. However, I want to plot them right next to each other and therefore I want the **width** and **height** of the tiles to be the same.

Is there a way to specify this in inches or cm?

I was looking for solutions and found `coord_fixed(ratio=1)`, but that didn't solve the problem completely.

Example of two different dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
  w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5)
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() +
coord_fixed(ratio=1)
p1 

df2=data.frame(x = rep(c("x","y","z"),3), 
               y=c("a","b","c","b","c","a","c","a","b"),
               z=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1))

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
coord_fixed(ratio=1)
p2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188986/r-ggplot2-make-two-geom-tile-plots-have-equal-height/24189239#24189239

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638294/geom-tile-and-facet-grid-facet-wrap-for-same-height-of-tiles/20639481#20639481

Comment: Sweet! I guess this makes my question a duplicate! I'm gonna delete it! Thanks @baptiste

Comment: you'll probably find that those old answers need adjustments

Comment: Yes... so there is no simple way to specify the height in some unit? I guess that would have been the easiest way to solve this

Comment: @baptiste I was trying both examples, but they don't work on my data. The number of tiles are zero.